# Deadlock with spin_until_future_complete in a timer

Tags: rclpy, spin

I am trying to understand how `rclpy` manages async calls, with a simple example: a timer waits 1sec and then calls a service.

```py
import rclpy
import rclpy.node
from std_srvs.srv import Empty

class ROSNode(rclpy.node.Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("test_node")
        self.timer = self.create_timer(1, self.run)
        self.client = self.create_client(Empty, "/test_service")
        print("Waiting 1sec...")

    def run(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        print("Calling service...")
        future = self.client.call_async(Empty.Request())
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)  # Deadlock happens here
        print("Service answered!")


def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = ROSNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

Deadlock happens, probably because the future is not resolved properly. Why?

To me, in terms of asynchronous execution, that code should be equivalent to:

```py
import asyncio

class NonROSNode():
    async def call_async(self):
        print("Calling service")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        print("Service answered!")

    async def run(self):
        print("Waiting 1sec...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await self.call_async()

asyncio.run(NonROSNode().run())
```

*(The server is started and answers properly to CLI requests)*

*(This can be fixed with `future.add_callback`. However `spin_until_future_complete` is the usage presented in the RCL tutorials, thus I would like to use it)*